# Epson OPOS ADK for .NET drivers for Windows 7

Tags: .net, device-driver, point-of-sale, opos, epson

Has anyone used Epson OPOS ADK for .NET for Windows 7. I tried to install Windows Vista drivers on Windows 7 since there are none available for Windows 7, but it did not work. Please share any suggestions or ideas that might have worked for you. I am using a TM-88IV receipt printer.

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier to use a generic text printer driver. Some of those specific OPOS drivers hog up CPU resource (either they are buggy or badly written). By using a generic text printer driver, you can send escape sequences to the printer to control the formatting as the printer uses the Epson ESC2 code sequences.

By the way, I guess the cash drawer is plugged into the back of the printer yes? Again, by using the generic printer driver, you can send a specific ESC control codes to it and the drawer should kick out - It may not be relevant to the question but thought I'd include that.

In light of this, it would be worth your while to check out [Microsoft's POS kit](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/products/readyproducts/posready/overview.mspx) for .NET which will make your life easier, this SDK sits on top of the OPOS drivers and you have the classes, methods, properties in the .NET World.

Comment: thanks a lot tommieb75. Yes i'll be using a cash drawer attached to the printer. Could you redirect me to some samples for using ESC2 codes in vb.net. I'm kinda new in this domain. Once again, thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Also what if i used Epson's APD driver and used its Status and Devmode APIs for communicating with driver. I failed to find any code samples for using ESC2 codes using vb.net.

Comment: @Irfnldrees: Epson should have on their website the codes neccessary to do this. Microsoft's POS Kit, in fact, will do all of this for you without worrying about the specific information such as escape codes etc and it is very comprehensive, for instance, there's a class you instantiate in a particular way, called Microsoft.PointOfService.CashDrawer, and one of the methods is called 'OpenCashDrawer'. Simple really. Download it and it will make life easier for yourself! Coupled with generic Text  Printer driver, you have it all! :) Feel free to ask any further questions.

Comment: @t0mm13b any idea why printer print half way and stopped? after printing about 30cm long...

Answer (score 1):

As Tom says, if you're are writing a .NET POS, you should probably be using Microsoft POS for .NET as the OPOS interface.

I use it in Vista on my development machine, so I imagine it would work in Windows 7 as well.

If you can't install some particular driver in Windows 7, then that would not really be very surprising. I doubt there are any Vista or Windows 7 POS machines out there yet.

One thing you could do in that case--where you can't get a driver to work on a development machine--would be to use the device simulators that come with POS for .NET. They are kind of poor (for instance, the printer simulator doesn't do any formatting) but they are better than nothing. I can't recall just now if they come with a cash drawer simulator. It wouldn't take you long to download it and find out though.

Answer (score 1):

A new set of OPOS drivers have been released for this that you can run under Windows 7 64bit successfully.

https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=soft&scat=39

Regards

AJ