# How to print Tickets/Invoice

Tags: c#, vb.net, invoice

Anyone know a class written in C # or VB.NET that serves to print tickets in a mini printer?
Printer: EPSON TM-U220PD

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your invoice is something you can contain within a `Stream` (e.g. file-system file, in-memory object, etc.), you can probably easily use the `PrintDocument` class in the .NET Framework.  MSDN has a simple example on how to use it.

This [assumes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) that you need to use this in a Windows Forms environment.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to talk to the printer directly: [How to send raw data to a printer by using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if your application is a POS application or not. But you could try looking into the [Microsoft POS for .NET v1.12 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=5355) & [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429024.aspx) and you could also look at this Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1925453/479512)

Here also is the [technical manual for your printer](http://www.icscale.com/TECH%20MANUALS/TMU220_TRG_RevD.pdf)
and the [APOS ADK](http://barcodingworks.com/?document_srl=1292) download.