# Silent Install Fails, Resultcode = -8 [Now ResultCode 0 but not installed]

Tags: command-line, installshield, silent-installer

I am trying to install a program silently (the program is old, has InstallShield v7.00). However, every time I run the command, it does nothing and the setup.log file states "ResultCode=-8".

That ResultCode indicates that an invalid path to the InstallShield Silent installation script file was specified (which I am assuming to be the response file I generated earlier, which is named setup.iss).

Setup.exe and setup.iss are both in the same folder. I tried specifying the exact path to both files, and not, as seen in the list of commands I have tried below:

```
"C:\Test\setup.exe" /s /f1"C:\Test\setup.iss"
setup.exe /s /f1 setup.iss (CMD directory is in C:\Test)
setup.exe /s (Thought it would just find the setup file automatically as they are in the same folder)
```

I am trying to install EPSON OPOS ADK, for which the installation manual states the exact commands I am using are correct.

There is no MSI file contained in the EXE file (or, if there is, I cannot extract it with WinRAR and I could not find it in ProgramData while the setup was running).

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or what I can do?

EDIT: Below is the contents of my setup.iss file:

```
[{0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-DlgOrder]
Dlg1={0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdWelcome-0
Count=7
Dlg2={0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdLicense2-0
Dlg3={0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdSetupType-0
Dlg4={0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdStartCopy-0
Dlg5={0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-AskOptions-0
Dlg6={0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdFinish-0
[{0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdWelcome-0]
Result=1
[{0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdLicense2-0]
Result=1
[{0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdSetupType-0]
szDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\OPOS\Epson2
Result=301
[{0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdStartCopy-0]
Result=1
[{0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-AskOptions-0]
Result=1
Sel-0=1
Sel-1=0
Sel-2=1
Sel-3=0
[Application]
Name=EPSON OPOS ADK
Version=031.000.01000
Company=SEIKO EPSON CORPORATION
Lang=0009
[{0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdFinish-0]
Result=1
bOpt1=0
bOpt2=0
```

EDIT 2:

So I ran the recording for the .iss file again, but this time instead of just doing "setup -r", I did "setup -r f1"C:\"" instead. This should make no difference other than telling it where to save the recording. However, I got a different .iss file out of it. Here it is:

```
[InstallShield Silent]
Version=v7.00
File=Response File
[File Transfer]
OverwrittenReadOnly=NoToAll
[{0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-DlgOrder]
Dlg0={0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-Uninstall-0
Count=7
Dlg1={0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdWelcome-0
Dlg2={0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdLicense2-0
Dlg3={0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdSetupType-0
Dlg4={0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdStartCopy-0
Dlg5={0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-AskOptions-0
Dlg6={0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdFinish-0
[{0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-Uninstall-0]
Uninstall=0
[{0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdWelcome-0]
Result=1
[{0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdLicense2-0]
Result=1
[{0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdSetupType-0]
szDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\OPOS\Epson2
Result=301
[{0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdStartCopy-0]
Result=1
[{0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-AskOptions-0]
Result=1
Sel-0=1
Sel-1=0
Sel-2=1
Sel-3=0
[Application]
Name=EPSON OPOS ADK
Version=031.000.01000
Company=SEIKO EPSON CORPORATION
Lang=0009
[{0EEDEE2B-7C9D-4584-B2B5-C28C93678BC1}-SdFinish-0]
Result=1
bOpt1=0
bOpt2=0
```

I was very happy when I saw it was different, and figured my issue would be solved. Well, not exactly.

Now, instead of getting ResultCode = -8, I am getting ResultCode = 0. A code of 0 indicates there was a successful installation. However, the program did NOT install. Nothing was touched. I noticed this before even looking at the code because it finished "installing" almost immediately after running the command, with no loading icons or anything.

So now, InstallShield is reporting that the program was successfully installed but it, in actuality, was not. I tried re-recording the .iss file numerous more times but I am just getting this same file now. The file is likely no longer the issue. However, I am at a loss for what the issue could be now.

Comment: See comment in my answer below on what seems to be lacking in the header section of that `setup.iss` file.

Comment: You might want to do a reboot of the machine in question, in case you have done a lot of experimenting with it. To "wipe the slate clean" if you like. Or as clean as possible. If the drivers are signed and you extract them from the setup, you could use [**DPInst.exe**](https://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/installing-device-driver) to install them yourself maybe?

Comment: If all extraction tricks fail, you can try to launch the `setup.exe` and wait for all files to extract to the temp folder and get them from there. [**Described towards the top here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987512/129130).

Comment: I just tried a reboot and unfortunately it is doing the same thing still. Got my hopes up, too, because it looked like it was "thinking" for a bit longer than usual. Ah well.

As far as installing drivers, unfortunately that is not quite what I am trying to install. I'm unsure if drivers are a part of what is being installed, but the end result of this installation is actually a usable program. The program is used to operate cash drawers in our bank. Here is a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/HfuHiQ9.png

Comment: Do you have an **application packaging** team in the bank? (somtimes referred to as **appliation repackaging**). [**As described here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46224987/129130), most bigger companies have such a team and their job is exactly to convert problematic installers to a format that can be deployed and managed remotely (silent install and uninstall). Something to check with management?

Comment: No, we do not. We are a relatively small bank. This is something that I would have to solve. It is not mission critical by any means, but I'd still like to solve it.

Comment: Unruly setups are generally repackaged using [a repackaging tool](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/tt_corp.htm). If you have a contact from the vendor, that is where I would go next, or an online forum or similar. [Skimming the linked documentation](https://partner.epson.jp/support/details/contents095/pdf/InstallManual.pdf) (`5.2`) it looks like you need to run a batch file - `CollectCopyInstallModules.bat` - and create a couple of settings files in a folder called `EpsonCopyInstallModules` that you then include in your silent installation media. Might not be the right documentation file.

Answer (score 0):

***Setup.iss***: I guess the real problem might be that there is an error in your `setup.iss` file. Can we see its content? Maybe the `setup.iss` you are using is for another `Setup.exe` entirely? Try re-generating a new one?

**UPDATE**: Maybe have a look here as well: **[Epson OPOS ADK for .NET drivers for Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925453/epson-opos-adk-for-net-drivers-for-windows-7)**

That `silent.iss` response file seems to lack a header section when compared with this documentation: [Performing Silent Installations and Uninstallations](https://resources.flexera.com/web/pdf/archive/silent_installs.pdf) (PDF, section "*InstallScript Installations*" page 3 onwards).

---

***Setup.exe Extract***: Maybe also make sure that this is not an MSI setup after all:

- ***Short version***: [Programmatically extract contents of InstallShield setup.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681252/programmatically-extract-contents-of-installshield-setup-exe/8694205#8694205)
- ***Long version***: [Extract MSI from EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe/24987512#24987512)

***And***:

- [Extracting from an MSI](https://superuser.com/questions/307678/how-do-i-extract-files-from-an-msi-package/307679#307679) ([administrative installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564619/what-is-the-purpose-of-administrative-installation-initiated-using-msiexec-a/5751980#5751980)).
- [How to deploy the Installshield MSI without having to run Setup.exe](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO4204.html)

---

***Sample Setup.exe Command Lines***: For inspiration [an ancient Itninja / AppDeploy PDF with sample Installshield setup.exe commands](http://www.itninja.com/static/090770319967727eb89b428d77dcac07.pdf) (I think the last few entries in the document were never finished, they just all say `Setup.exe /uninst` - so just ignore them). Did you try the `/SMS` parameter? I don't see how that would solve your particular problem, but you should know about the switch anyway.

---

***Some Links***:

- [InstallShield Error Codes (Setup.log)](https://www.blackice.com/Help/Tools/PrinterDriver%20Demo/RTK_Full_WebHelp/InstallShield_Error_Codes_Setup_log.htm)
- [InstallShield Setup Silent Installation Switches](https://www.itninja.com/blog/view/installshield-setup-silent-installation-switches)
- [Performing Silent Installations and Uninstallations](https://resources.flexera.com/web/pdf/archive/silent_installs.pdf) (PDF)
- [EPSON OPOS ADK for .NET Manual](https://partner.epson.jp/support/details/contents095/pdf/InstallManual.pdf) (PDF)

***Installshield 2018 Help File***:

- [Setup.exe and Update.exe Command-Line Parameters](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm#ref-command-linetools_1056566962_1021611%3FTocPath%3DReference%7CCommand-Line%2520Tools%7C_____9)
- [Advanced UI and Suite/Advanced UI Setup.exe Command-Line Parameters](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/SteSetupexeParam.htm#ref-command-linetools_1056566962_1050787%3FTocPath%3DReference%7CCommand-Line%2520Tools%7C_____10)
- [Setup.exe (InstallScript Projects)](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/SetupExeInstallScript.htm#ref-command-linetools_1056566962_1033363%3FTocPath%3DReference%7CCommand-Line%2520Tools%7C_____11)

Comment: I appreciate your comment. Unfortunately, most of those resources and links aren't helpful, as they contain basic info on the commands I am using, and do not contain any actual troubleshooting information regarding my error.

I did, however, have some luck with changing my command for recording the .iss file. It did not fix the issue, but it did change it into a new issue. I added more to the OP again to reflect this.

Thank you again for your reply!

Comment: Did you run the silent install with **admin rights**? Did you try with the **SMS switch** described above? With regards to the links in the answer. I do it this way because I try to write for the community. Hence the attempt to be "generic" and "expansive". Not always the right approach - that I can agree with - but in this case I think the links might prove helpful for others - or even yourself as the problem you see "evolves". Time will show.

Comment: Oh no, I definitely did not mean my comment in a bad way. I absolutely understand the necessity of it.

Yes, I have been running with administrator rights the entire time and I tried using the SMS switch to no avail.

Comment: No worries, I just point this "generic answer" issue out every now and then because my answers might seem to miss the plot entirely I guess. The info is in there I believe. I added another comment above. I am sure we can get this issue resolved. Running old Installshield `setup.exe` files reliable in silent mode is a notorious problem by the way.